# using the Atmega328P

Tags: arduino, atmega328p

if I take the micro controller (ATmega328P) from the Arduino board and simply place it on to a breadboard, do I still need to upload the boot loader ?

Comment: if the boot loader was on the microcontroller before you unsoldered it, it's still going to be there.

Comment: (but it's a rather uncommon thing to do. Make sure all the components that the microcontroller needs to function are still there on the breadboard – power supply decoupling caps, external oscillator, …)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to upload the Bootloader, it's already in the chip.
**BUT**, when you unplug the ATMega328 you no longer have the serial connection support over USB.

If you upload a sketch while the ATMega328 is on the Arduino board and then put it in a breadboard, it will work providing you don't need serial/USB and you have the correct oscillator (16Mhz) on your breadboard.

There are a couple of approaches to create your own breadboard projects:

1. Keep your Arduino intact and buy some ATMega328 chips. You can use the Arduino as an ISP to program the chips without needing a serial/USB connection.
2. Use an Arduino Nano. This plugs directly into your breadboard and has everything you need onboard.

Start reading [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone), this has all been done before.

Comment: Yes you do not need to load the bootloader again unless you plan to use a FT232 breakout or somthing similar for uploading sketches 

I always feel it is better to use something like the USBasp to upload hex code to the MCU if it is not within the Arduino Board

Answer (score 2):

No, the bootloader is already installed.  You will need a 16 MHz crystal, two 22pF caps, a 10K resistor (reset pullup), and four 0.1uF caps - one for Vcc, one for Avcc, one for Aref, and one for DTR if you plan to add a 6-pin header to plug an FTDI Basic (or equivalent clone) for downloading code via the Arduino IDE, or use the serial port for debugging your code with the serial monitor - basically the same as a Promini less the 5V regulator.

Do not connect Aref to 5V - just the cap to Gnd.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to program it using the Arduino tools you need the boot-loader. (which boot-loader will be present if you removed the ATMega328 from an Arduino board)

If it is already progammed you don't need the boot loader
If you intend to use a SPI programmer (eg: AVRASP) then you do not need the boot loader.